# Will forking more workers allow me to balance CPU-heavy work?

Tags: node.js

I love node.js' evented model, but it only takes you so far - when you have a function (say, a request handler for HTTP connections) that does a lot of heavy work on the CPU, it's still "blocking" until its function returns. That's to be expected. But what if I want to balance this out a bit, so that a given requests takes longer to process but the overall response time is shorter, using the operarting system's ability to schedule the processes?

My production code uses node's wonderfully simple Cluster module to fork a number of workers equal to the number of cores the system's CPU has. Would it be bad to fork more than this - perhaps two or three workers per core? I know there'll be a memory overhead here, but memory is not my limitation. What reading I did mentioned that you want to avoid "oversubscribing", but surely on a modern system you're not going crazy by having two or three processes vying for time on the processor.

Answer (score 3):

I think your idea sounds like a good one; especially because many processors support [hyperthreading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperthreading). Hyperthreading is *not* magical and won't suddenly double your application's speed or throughput but it *can* make sense to have another thread ready to execute in a core when the first thread needs to wait for a memory request to be filled.

Be careful when you start multiple workers: the Linux kernel *really* prefers to keep processes executing on the same processor for their entire lifetime to provide for strong cache affinity. This makes enough sense. But I've seen several CPU-hungry processes vying for a *single* core or worse a single hyperthread instance rather than the system re-balancing the processes across all cores or all siblings. Check your processor affinities by running `ps -eo pid,psr,comm` (or whatever your favorite `ps(1)` command is; add the `psr` column).

To combat this you might want to start your workers with an explicitly limited CPU affinity:

```
taskset -c 0,1 node worker 1
taskset -c 2,3 node worker 2
taskset -c 4,5 node worker 3
taskset -c 6,7 node worker 4
```

Or perhaps start eight, one per HT sibling, or eight and confine each one to their own set of CPUs, or perhaps sixteen, confine four per core or two per sibling, etc. (You *can* go nuts trying to micromanage. I suggest keeping it simple if you can.) See the `taskset(1)` manpage for details.

Comment: Thanks @Drasill; I'll note in passing that newer Linux kernel versions appear far more ready to migrate tasks among processors, making the `taskset` invocation less important than it once was. I'll happily leave this though because it'll take a decade for all those older Linux installs to be migrated or replaced with newer versions.